# how can i align my floating button to the bottom of the page in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, gridview

//Parent View

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/back4">
```

//Relative Layout Child of ScrollView

```
<RelativeLayout  

        android:layout_width="match_parent"    
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">
```

//Grid View with Parent Relative Layout. Grid View not allowing floating button to align bottom

```
    <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:verticalSpacing="50dp">

    </GridView>
```

//Floating Button adding to Bottom of screen

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton   

            android:id="@+id/addNew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/addbutton"/>
```

//End of Relative Layout

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

//End of Scroll View

Comment: Remove android:layout_below="@+id/gridview".

Answer (score 2):

Make some changes to your FloatingActionButton XML. Hope this works for you!

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addNew"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/addbutton" />
```

Also, there is no need of vertically scrolling ScrollView as GridView is also a vertically scrolling widget(GridView).